# How to change column width in confluence's table-plus macro?

Tags: confluence

I tried to change columns width in Confluence wiki markup, but I can't understand why it's not working. I have something like this:

```
{table-plus:columnTypes=S,-,.|autoNumber=true|sortColumn=3 
|columnAttributes=,,style="background:yellow; font-size:14pt;"} 
|| Name || Phone || TCP || 
| John | 555-1234 | 192.168.1.10 | 
| Mary | 555-2134 | 192.168.1.12 | 
| Bob | 555-4527 | 192.168.1.9 | 

{table-plus}
```

I know that "columnAttributes" attribute adds CSS to cells (according to this [link](https://wiki.mq.edu.au/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65963269)), but in confluence 3.5 it's not working in my case.

Comment: http://ysgitdiary.blogspot.com/2012/05/how-to-convert-csv-to-confluence-wiki.html

Comment: nice post, but i'm not write any line of perl code for all time(. i like java for this thing, can you tell me why you use perl for this purposes?

Answer (score 2):

Here's the syntax for setting the width in each column, formatted for readability. (Remember that macros must contain no whitespace.):

```
{table-plus:columnTypes=S,-,.
 |autoNumber=true|sortColumn=3|width=100%
 |columnAttributes=
    style="background:yellow;font-size:14pt;style=width:33%",
    style="background:yellow;font-size:14pt;style=width:33%",
    style="background:yellow;font-size:14pt;style=width:33%"
}

|| Name     || Phone   || TCP         || 
| John      | 555-1234 | 192.168.1.10 | 
| Mary      | 555-2134 | 192.168.1.12 | 
| Bob       | 555-4527 | 192.168.1.9  | 

{table-plus}
```

This produces:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use table-plus macro, as described in [your link](https://wiki.mq.edu.au/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=65963269):

```
{table-plus:width=100%|columnAttributes=style=width:33%, style=width:33%, style=width:33%}
```